# How can I write a generic function that discriminates between signed and unsigned int?

Tags: rust, traits

I was wondering if it was possible to discriminate between a signed and unsigned int in Rust. In `std::num` we have `Int`, `UnsignedInt : Int` and `SignedInt : Int + Neg`, so those two are not mutually exclusive.

In the simplest case, would it be possible to write a simple function `fn<T: Int>is_signed(value: T) -> bool` that would return true when a signed value is passed (e.g. `i32`)? Is there a better way of doing this?

Edit in response to a comment below: a real-world example is wrapping a C FFI where functions that return signed integer types indicate an error by returning a `-1` whereas functions returning uints indicate error by returning `0` (this, plus it got me interested in what's an idiomatic way of doing it in Rust).

Comment: I'm curious to know what this ability will allow you to do.

Comment: @Shepmaster edited the post for clarity. Thanks

Comment: Note that `std::Int` is deprecated in 1.0, and replace by [isize](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.isize.html)

Comment: @aldanor thanks for the info, but I still feel like something is missing. If you have a `i32`, then you already know it's signed. Do you want to create some kind of overloaded method that would automatically check the appropriate error code? Like `wrap_error(c_fn_that_returns_signed())` and `wrap_error(c_fn_that_returns_unsigned())`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's not the `std::Int` trait that's being deprecated, but rather `int`/`uint` types. The `Int`, `SignedInt` and `UnsignedInt` traits are still implemented for `isize` and `usize`.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose Are you sure? It looks like `std::Int` is implemented for `isize`. Note that `std:Int` != `int`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yep, that's exactly the idea! When there's hundreds of such functions, half of them returning ints and the other half uints (of all possible sizes), it'd be nice to have a single wrapper to check for  errors so it begs for a generic. I know how to do this in other languages e.g. D, but not in Rust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of the methods on `Int` to implement `is_signed`:

```
fn is_signed<T: Int>(x: T) -> bool {
    let mv: T = Int::min_value();
    let z: T = Int::zero();
    mv < z
}
```

And then use it like:

```
is_signed(5i)
```

Or if you remove the unneeded parameter `x` from `is_signed`:

```
is_signed<i32>
```

However, this would not be very efficient or idiomatic. In your case of checking error codes, it would be better to define a trait with the behavior you want, and implement it for each possible type:

```
trait IsError {
    fn is_error(self) -> bool;
}

impl IsError for isize {
    fn is_error(self) -> bool { self < 0 }
}

impl IsError for usize {
    fn is_error(self) -> bool { self == 0 }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do the same as your latter idea (it seems cleaner), but can you somehow implement it for `SignedInt` and `UnsignedInt` instead of concrete types?

Comment: @Shepmaster If you try, the compiler complains about conflicting impls. Which is valid, nothing prevents you from implementing both `SignedInt` and `UnsignedInt` on a type. I think this is the best we can do.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner That's the first thing I naturally tried to do, using `SignedInt` and `UnsignedInt` directly until realizing just what you mentioned.

Comment: It also looks like `min_value()` and `zero()` are `#[unstable]` in the `Int` trait, oh well.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought about implementing both traits on one type. That would be strange in this example! We could create a macro to make it easier to wrap up all the signed types and unsigned though.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner Thanks for the answer! Just wonder what you meant by "if you remove the unneeded parameter from is_signed: is_signed<int32>">?

Comment: @aldanor I was referring to the `(x: T)`, which isn't needed but might help drive type inference.

Comment: hi @wingedsubmariner, can you update your answer for 2024, please? There is no `Int` in rust now, maybe `num` crate can be used for that?